# How to make a file run on startup using batch or VBScript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I need to schedule a task using a batch file that will make my program run on startup. However, I can't find out how to do that using any scripts that are pre-installed on Windows.

Comment: So you expect us to search the web for you??

Comment: You also didn't even bother to research [ask] on SO.  Not only that, but it appears that you were too lazy to even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].

Comment: Not to mention that this kind of question doesn't belong on SO in the first place. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is a better place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use: Control panel -> Administrative tools -> Task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a shortcut to your batch file within the `startup` group